# Remainder modulo 8

Tags: modular-arithmetic

A number is given:  $1234513151313653211415515253$

Is there any way to find out the reminder when it divided by 8? What will be happened if  I use MOD rules here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you divide by $8$, you only need to worry about the last 3 numbers. So $1234513151313653211415515253$ mod $8$ becomes $253$ mod $8$.  Now it's a cake walk!

Comment: why last three digits only essential?

Comment: We know that $8$ goes into $1000$.  That means that any number that ends with $000$ such as $123234000$ will be divisible by $8$. Therefore, we only need to check the last $3$ numbers.

For instance, we can write $1234513151313653211415515253$ as $1234513151313653211415515000+253$.  Since $8$ goes into $1234513151313653211415515000$, we only have to check $253$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to look at the last 3 digits. Hence remainder is $253 \mod 8 = 5$